# How to force a MatMenu (mat-menu) to open below trigger?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I need my MatMenu to always open below the trigger, even if the currently scrolled viewport does not have room. I have tried `yPosition="below"`, but it will still check for room before opening it above the trigger, even if there is less room above. Here is a basic example from the docs:
[image: MatMenu Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forcing MatMenu to always obey a position is not possible. The position feature should be thought of as a position *preference* only. MatMenu will always try to avoid display cutoff by re-positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Though not shown in the overview section of the docs, if you check the [API](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api) section of the menu component you will see the properties that the MatMenu directive has. In there you'll see the `overlapTrigger` property in which you can set whether the component should overlap with it's trigger or not.

To achieve what I assume is your desired end result, you should have the following line:

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" yPosition="below" [overlapTrigger]="false">
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but even with that, the menu will be allowed to cover the trigger, but it can still choose to expand up or down based on available room when I just want to to expand down.

Comment: You could try setting the properties of how you want the menu to be from the ts instead of the template, it worked for me one time where for an unknown reason to me the mat-menu was not responding to the values I sent on the template. Think you could make a stackblitz replicating the issue?